# How to connect module routes to routes in Laravel 10

Tags: laravel-routing, laravel-10, laravel-controller, laravel-modules

I was facing an issue in the view file of laravel 10 where I was not connected with the module view to the main index.blade.php

I was add like these @include("dailyprocess::dailyproces", ['processes' => $processes]) in index.blade.php but it return an error undefined variable $processes